# Azure IoT-Hub Job Query returns to few results

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I already successfully scheduled a lot of jobs using the REST API of the Azure IoT-Hub as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-jobs. Namely I scheduled jobs to execute direct methods.

But, when I try to query the status of the scheduled jobs (as described on the same page), I always get only one entry: the status of the first successfully scheduled job. How do I get the status of all jobs?

My query was:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://<iot-hub-name>.azure-devices.net/jobs/v2/query?api-version=2018-06-30 \
  -H 'Authorization: SharedAccessSignature <sas-token>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' -o response.json
```

The SAS Token I used above was the same as for scheduling the job. Thus, there is no authentication issue.

The formatted response just contains 1 entry despite that I already scheduled 11 jobs:

```
[
    {
        "jobId": "job02",
        "queryCondition": "deviceId = simple_thermostat",
        "createdTime": "2022-03-02T15:59:27.4093129Z",
        "startTime": "2022-03-02T15:20:15Z",
        "endTime": "2022-03-02T15:59:34.5969497Z",
        "maxExecutionTimeInSeconds": 10000,
        "type": "scheduleDeviceMethod",
        "cloudToDeviceMethod": {
            "methodName": "getMaxMinReport",
            "payload": "hello",
            "responseTimeoutInSeconds": 300,
            "connectTimeoutInSeconds": 0
        },
        "status": "completed",
        "deviceJobStatistics": {
            "deviceCount": 0,
            "failedCount": 0,
            "succeededCount": 0,
            "runningCount": 0,
            "pendingCount": 0
        }
    }
]
```

PS: Getting the status of a single job works as expected. Like using this request:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://<iot-hub-name>.azure-devices.net/jobs/v2/job11?api-version=2018-06-30 \
  -H 'Authorization: SharedAccessSignature <sas-token>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' -o response.json
```

But, job11 is never returned in the query above.

Comment: are you receiving a response header **x-ms-continuation**? if yes, then call the query request again while this header exist it.

Comment: @roman-kiss Thanks, for the hint that I can find the continuationToken within the header. I missed that. But unfortunately, if I specify the continuationToken from the first request in another request, I get the same response as in the first request: same body with just the first job and same continuationToken in the header. Looks like my query parameters are just ignored. :(

Comment: using the Azure CLI, you can get the list of your jobs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub/job?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-hub-job-list-examples

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Roman Kiss, the continuation token can be found in the header of the first response. To save the header via curl one must specify the option `-D`. So, the first query must look like:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://<iot-hub-name>.azure-devices.net/jobs/v2/query?api-version=2018-06-30 \
  -H 'Authorization: SharedAccessSignature <sas-token>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
  -D response_hdr.txt -o response.json
```

Then response_hdr.txt will contain a line like this:

```
x-ms-continuation: eyJzb3VyY2UiOiJkZGIiLCJ0b3RhbFJldHJpZXZlZENvdW50Ijo4LCJjb250aW51YXRpb25Ub2tlbiI6Ilt7XCJ0b2tlblwiOm51bGwsXCJyYW5nZVwiOntcIm1pblwiOlwiMDVDMUU3RkZGRkZGRkFcIixcIm1heFwiOlwiRkZcIn19XSJ9
```

**But**, this continuation token must not be specified in the URL as stated in the Microsoft docs. Instead it must be provided in the header of the subsequent query:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://<iot-hub-name>.azure-devices.net/jobs/v2/query?api-version=2018-06-30 \
  -H 'Authorization: SharedAccessSignature <sas-token>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
  -H 'x-ms-continuation: <continuation_token_from_previous_query>' \
  -D response_hdr.txt -o response.json
```

This query will deliver a new continuation token. It looks pretty similar, but it is not identical.